# Android functions simultaneously

Tags: android

This is my code:

```
protected void loadvide(Chan channel) {
        Rtmpdump dump = new Rtmpdump();
        dump.parseString(channel.getUrl());
        startActivity(new Intent(this,VideoViewDemo.class));
    }
```

The code works, but I have a problem.

The problem is, when I execute the aplication, first execute this part to my code:

```
Rtmpdump dump = new Rtmpdump();
            dump.parseString(channel.getUrl());
```

and the second part: `startActivity(new Intent(this,VideoViewDemo.class));` not work, because the second part begin work when finish the first part.

But I would like that when I start the application, the first and second parts of the code are executed simultaneously.

Comment: Then create a thread and do the first part inside the thread and let the below code run normally in the Main UI thread itself.

Comment: You can use Async Task

Comment: Thanks andro and black, but I am new, and I don't know do what you say.

Please can you make me a example to my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Async Task for this

```
private class MyAsyncClass extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         //Do your task here
         Rtmpdump dump = new Rtmpdump();
        dump.parseString(channel.getUrl());
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         startActivity(new Intent(this,VideoViewDemo.class));
     }
 }
```

Check this link as per android.developer = > http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Check this for few tutorial = > http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html